# LazyInitializationException when Persisting newly created Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have an entity that has a `ManyToMany` relationship to another entity.
Let say Child has a collection of hobbies. Whenever I want to create a new child, i do this:

```
Child child = new Child();
List<Hobby> hobbies = hobbiesDAO.retrieveAll(); //Get all hobbies from database
child.setHobbies(hobbies); // Error is thrown here
childDao.create(child); // persist to database
```

A `LazyInitializationException` is `thrown`. I think it is because the newly created Child entity is not yet attached to the `Session`? How can I attach the newly created entity to the session so it will not throw an `exception` when adding the related entities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

define the hobies to be eagerly loaded unless you are really needed it to be lazily loaded which hibernate does defaultly

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Hobby> getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }
```

Comment: Eager loading is not acceptable on my current situation as it involves a lot of data. As for FetchType.LAZY, it throws LazyInitializationException upon persisting.